# What does the word “and” imply in context of a probability problem?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

The question in the title might be a little vague, so I will specify the context. The probability question in context asks what is the probability of getting **a black card and a king** when a card is drawn from a regular deck of 52 cards. Now the answer key states that the probability is $\frac{7}{13}$ . This is where I have a doubt. The explanation goes on to show that there are 26 black cards which include 2 kings and the remaining 2 kings add up to a total of 28 favourable outcomes. But the word **and** implies that the card which we draw must be black and king, meaning there are only two possibilities : the king of clubs and the king of spades. So my answer is $\frac{1}{26}$. Can someone please elaborate and verify which of the answers are correct ?

Comment: In my opinion you are right and the context is wrong. The probability of getting "a black card and a king" means the probability of getting a black king.

Comment: $\frac{28}{52}=\frac{7}{13}$ is the probability of selecting a card which is a black card *or* a king

Comment: @Henry exactly. But the question says _and_